# How To Use Ads With Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to inject 1 ad in the popup created by my extension. How could I do so? Because when I try to add direct code provided by adsense, it shows "Refuse to execute script because of CPP".

Is there any way? I'm inserting ad on page and looks like it is allowed by chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use Google Adsense With Chrome Extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424397/is-it-safe-to-use-google-adsense-with-chrome-extension)

Comment: @Xan I asked you there is it possible to use 3rd party ads with it then?

Comment: And is it possible to inject my own ad on a page user visits with the extension without modifying the dignity of that page?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli It's a duplicate, since it's asked by the same user today and contains the answer to his question.

Comment: @Xan since that your answer on the other question both answers this and the previous one, and since that both questions are asked from the same user, you're right.

Comment: @Xan It is not a duplicate. The other one asks whether AdSense is allowed by policy, while this question asks how to embed an advert in an extension without a CSP error. A possible answer is to use an iframe.